# How can I properly pass data through args in x86-64 assembly on Linux?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Passing data through args in assembly x86-64 on the linux

Through args I need to get a file name and an integer number. But when I try to upload it to the register, I don't get what I want.

Makefile:

```
AS = /usr/bin/nasm
LD = /usr/bin/ld

ASFLAGS = -g -f elf64
LDFLAGS = -static

SRCS = lab.s
OBJS = $(SRCS:.s=.o)

EXE = lab

all: $(SRCS) $(EXE)

clean:
        rm -rf $(EXE) $(OBJS)

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

.s.o:
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

lab.s:

```
bits    64
;       Print text file
global  _start
_start:
        cmp     dword [rsp], 3

        mov     rax, [rsp]
        mov     rdx, [rsp + 8]
        mov     rbx, [rsp + 16]
        mov     rsi, [rsp + 24]
        mov     rsi, [rsi]

        mov     eax, 1          ; write
        mov     edi, 1          ; standart_output
        mov     rsi, [rsp + 16] ; name
        xor     edx, edx        ; size = 0 ->

find_size:
        cmp     byte [rsi+rdx], 0
        je      print
        inc     edx
        jmp     find_size

print:
        syscall

        mov     edi, 1
        mov     eax, 60
        syscall
```

There is the address of the number on the first photo into the rsi register. And on the second photo, I'm trying to move the number itself into the rsi register.

[the address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FhHy.png)
[the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty9V6.png)

Comment: You don't need the `mov rsi, [rsi]` since you want rsi to be the address not the value. You can see in your second image that you loaded the value (input was `89` apparently).

Comment: `write(fd, buf, 0)` isn't going to output anything.